# Disabled Twilio loudspeaker audio/video call in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, twilio

While doing video/audio call using Twilio then by default it's place the voice over loudspeaker also the call has lot of noise.

I want to override the loudspeaker and also to minimize the noise.

Comment: What do you want to play the audio over? Which Twilio SDK are you using?

Comment: I want to use it as normal phone call
not on loud speaker.
Using TwilioVideo 1.0.0

Comment: @DanialHussain Have you solved this issue? If yes, Please tell me how can I solve this particular issue.

Comment: @Nilesh yes i have solved this issue.

Comment: Can you please add here whatever you have done for this issue, that will be helpful for me.

Comment: TVIAudioController *audioController = [TVIAudioController sharedController];
[audioController setAudioOutput:TVIAudioOutputVoiceChatDefault];
or
[audioController setAudioOutput:TVIAudioOutputVideoChatDefault];

Comment: Thanks Danial, much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

You can [set the audio output for Twilio Video](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/video/configuring-audio-video-inputs-and-outputs#selecting-a-specific-audio-output) using the [TVIAudioController](https://media.twiliocdn.com/sdk/ios/video/releases/1.0.0-beta7/docs/Classes/TVIAudioController.html). If you set the `audioOutput` to `TVIAudioOutputVoiceChatDefault` then the audio should come out of the phone speaker, not the loudspeaker.

As for noise, I'm not sure how to help you there. Do you mean the voice is distorted? Or that you are hearing background noise?

Comment: The noise is on loudspeaker it's doing echo and whistle like sound when doing video call.

Comment: Do you have two devices in the same room that you are testing on?

Comment: The noise is likely to just be feedback from the devices hearing each other and sending the noise through the connection, in an increasingly loud loop. I'd either test with one device in a different room or with at least one on mute.

Comment: Thanks. Now i get the idea

Comment: @philnash This is not working. TVIAudioOutput is not there in 2.0 How can we achieve in latest sdk?

Comment: There are docs on specifying audio output in version 2 here: https://www.twilio.com/docs/video/ios-v2-configuring-audio-video-inputs-and-outputs#selecting-specific-audio-routes

Answer (score 1):

*(Posted answer on behalf of the question author).*

```
TVIAudioController *audioController = [TVIAudioController sharedController]; 
[audioController setAudioOutput:TVIAudioOutputVoiceChatDefault]; 
//[audioController setAudioOutput:TVIAudioOutputVideoChatDefault];
```

The sound problem is due to same place where we are testing.